# How can I set a select menu's border radius in jquery mobile with css

Tags: css

My global theme has rounded corners set a 0em, no rounded borders but there are a few elements I'd like to apply a rounded theme to. I tried adding this at the end of my css files,

```
.rounded {
-moz-border-radius:    2em    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
-webkit-border-radius:    2em    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
border-radius:    2em    /*{global-radii-blocks}*/;
}
```

and then add that class to the dom elements like so

```
 <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <select name="select_networks" id="select_networks" data-inline="true" class="rounded">
            <option value="1/1">Everyone</option>
            <option value="2/1">Friends</option>
        </select>
        <select name="select_sort" id="select_sort" data-inline="true" class="rounded">
            <option value="1">Points</option>
            <option value="2">New</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

but not luck so far, any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a particular platform this isn't working on? Seems to work fine in chrome and ff. http://jsfiddle.net/mrtsherman/AUJxA/

Comment: Hmm well I'm running it on an android device via phonegap, ill take at the default css to see if i can figure something out

Comment: I don't think you will be able to style native select lists in android default browser. They recently ported Chrome to Android. May work in that.

Comment: There has to be a pure css solution because if I set the corners in the jquery mobile theme roller http://jquerymobile.com/themeroller/index.php?style_id=20111028-2 it will style listviews and eveyrthing else accordingly.

Comment: Actually even setting the border radius in the themeroller doesn't work either. I think because its wrapped in the controlgroup

Answer (score 0):

Do you try to use `!important` to force the element must follow the style in css?

Sometimes, although use inline style, my element still follow the parent's element's style, try with `!important`